# Logging in Identity Server 4 - .Net Core 2.2

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

I am trying to enable logging in Identity Server 4 by following their guide in the [docs](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/logging.html) that uses `Serilog`.  Not sure if the docs are out of date but there are two extension methods `.UseSerilog()` and `.Build()` from `CreateWebHostBuilder()` that throw an error, though I have the `Serilog` package installed:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Console.Title = "IdentityServer4.Postgres";

            Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
            .MinimumLevel.Debug()
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("System", LogEventLevel.Warning)
            .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication", LogEventLevel.Information)
            .Enrich.FromLogContext()
            .WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate: "[{Timestamp:HH:mm:ss} {Level}] {SourceContext}{NewLine}{Message:lj}{NewLine}{Exception}{NewLine}", theme: AnsiConsoleTheme.Literate)
            .CreateLogger();

            var seed = args.Contains("/seed");
            if (seed)
            {
                args = args.Except(new[] { "/seed" }).ToArray();
            }

            var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

            if (seed)
            {
                var config = host.Services.GetRequiredService<IConfiguration>();
                var connectionString = config.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection");
                SeedData.EnsureSeedData(connectionString);
                return;
            }

            host.Run();
        }

        public static IWebHostBuilder CreateWebHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                .UseSerilog()
                .Build();
    }
```

**Update**

[image: Serilog Error]

Comment: what error\exception is thrown?

Comment: I've just updated my post

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `UseSerilog()` extension method is provided by the NuGet package [Serilog.AspNetCore](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Serilog.AspNetCore/). You likely need to add this NuGet package to your project, then add a `using Serilog` statement.